# Download and unzip dataset directly in Azure

Tags: azure

I need to load and unzip a 27 giga dataset directly in my azure account to work on it with a spark instance with the textFile function to do some machine learning. How can I do it?

I would like to write more, but I have spent so many hours surfing on the internet and still I am not able to achieve anything useful.

This is the dataset:

https://academicgraphwe.blob.core.windows.net/graph-2016-02-05/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If directly means from that location to your VM, then the most simple way, in my opinion, is to use [AzCopy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/).

For example, in your case it can be like that:
AzCopy /Source:https://academicgraphwe.blob.core.windows.net/graph-2016-02-05/ /Dest:C:\myfolder /SourceKey:key /Pattern:"abc.txt"

Install AzCopy on your VM and run the command. You need no SourceKey here as it looks like your dataset is in publicly available blob. But change your link to the needed location (because it is going to some kind of list of links).

Comment: I have done  it manually using ssh. Now that I have the .txt files in my Ubuntu VM now how can i save those .txt to blob storage?

Comment: http://storageexplorer.com/ runs on Linux and the simplest way to upload something from local disc to azure blob.

Comment: I have to install it on my local machine and manage all my storage remotely, right without using ssh or anything else, right?

Comment: ok I have installed it on my laptop, the problem is that he makes me download the whole .vhd on my pc that is not feasible since is 150 giga. I just would like look the filesystem of the .vhd and create blobs from specific .txt files, doing all the datatransfer in the cloud

Comment: Install it on your Ubuntu vm in the Azure. Or the vm you mentioned is not in the cloud?

Comment: the vm is in the cloud, but since the program has a graphical user interface i don't know how should i use it remotly

Comment: for remotely I mean via SSH

Comment: Yep, as i see your question was answered by other - i would go with the VNC and graphical interface for your VM, and using GUI for managing the storage, but if you do not want to do both of that, then Linux CLI is the solution.

Comment: I could sound naive but I didn't know there was the possibility to have a remote graphical interface! Could you tell me a starting point in using those services?

Comment: That is what i meant - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2013/11/12/running-a-remote-desktop-on-a-windows-azure-linux-vm/